# Is there a way to format QR Code generation to show as a phone number when scanned, rather than text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qr-code

I can generate QR Codes with data inside of them, but they always show up as "text" or "web-url" using this method. I know that when you scan some QR Codes it will appear as a phone number, so is there a way to specify that I want this data to be stored as a phone number in the program?

This is running the newest version of qrcode and pillow, and Python 3.7 64-bit. The QR Code terminology is quite foreign to me so I have not tried to mess with the format settings yet.

```
import qrcode


def make_code(data, filename='qr.png'):
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        error_correction = qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_H,
        border = 4,
        box_size = 50
    )
    qr.add_data(data)
    qr.make(fit=True)
    img = qr.make_image()
    img.save(filename)
```

Comment: A URL can refer to a phone number see e.g. https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2012/12/using-url-scheme-for-telephone-numbers.html